# Building inverted indexing system with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am building a mobile service that require a lot of search queries.

The service is based on MySQL data system, and search query is not enough to make a fast search service.

Therefore, I decided to use inverted indexing system:

```
index    Documents
1        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h
2        c, k, i, j, k
```

This is a simple construction for the inverted indexing system.

I assume that there will be more than thousand documents for one row.

**I am not sure what kind of type and length that I should use for the 'Documents' column?**

I selected VARCHAR(100000) for now. Is it possible to set the length like 9999999?

Comment: VARCHAR(100000) is probably not the right choice - I'm tempted to say ever, but especially not in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Data structure:

   ```
   index document
     1      a
     1      b
     1      c
    ...
     2      c
     2      k
   ```

   `index` type `INT`, `document` type `CHAR(1)`. Primary key as set of `index` and `document`.

   Queries will perform very fast with this data structure.
   By the way, the structure I propose is [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).
2. From MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual ([The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)):

> [...] `VARCHAR` [...] The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that your data structure is much faster than my data structure. It's good to know that 65,535 is maximum for VARCHAR in PHP 5.0.3.

Comment: @james You may find these questions interesting too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320633/first-time-database-design-am-i-overengineering, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934577/should-i-normalize-my-db-or-not

Comment: Does any kind of space issues arise in this method? What are other popular methods?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this will get ugly, but that being said, your varchar size would cover it, or you could look into TEXT, mediumTEXT, or longTEXT:

```
TEXT    65,535 bytes    ~64kb
MEDIUMTEXT   16,777,215 bytes   ~16MB
LONGTEXT    4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB
```